# Using JS to target & scroll to bottom of a table

Tags: javascript, html

Some context: I'm trying to build a scraper that pulls all the data from a dynamic table.

I want to target a table on the page with no specific class/ID (though it is the 71st instance of a table on the document) and then have it scroll to the bottom of that table to load all the data.

However, I've tried using onScroll and most of the scroll methods are for the Window object. Since this table is inside of a scrollable div.. I've tried targeting it with different selectors, but I keep getting TypeError: Undefined is not an object.

TLDR in 1 line of js, target the 71st table element, and scroll it to the bottom.

Comment: Why would you need to scroll this table when you can scrape the data via DOM?

Comment: @RishatMuhametshin Because the DOM isn't being dynamically loaded with the data until you scroll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one line? You could do something like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('table')[70].querySelector('tbody tr:last-child').scrollIntoView();
```

A litle explanation....

```
document.querySelectorAll('table')[70]; //finds the 71st table in the page
querySelector('tbody tr:last-child'); //find the last row of the 71st table;
scrollIntoView(); //Scroll the element into view (scroll to the bottom of the table)
```

Comment: Great thanks that worked, I think it's cause I was calling a scroll onto the table element not the tbody.  You are a saint.